# Firebase mode detected. warning: unable to find GoogleService-Info.plist in app bundle, dSYMs will not be uploaded

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I have setup all these steps and bundle id on Firebase Dashboard and tried crash many times but not getting any report.

1. pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.6'
2. pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.1'
3. In Build phase added run Script : **"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"**
4. Debug Inforation Format : DWARF with dSYM File
5. running in simulator with following steps

   - (IBAction)crashButtonTapped:(id)sender { [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]; }
   - Click play_arrow Build and then run the current scheme in Xcode to build your app on a device or simulator.
   - Click stop Stop running the scheme or action in Xcode to close the initial instance of your app. This initial instance includes a debugger that interferes with Crashlytics.
   - Open your app again from the simulator or device. Touch Crash to crash the app.

**@Alexizamerican** my app's bundle id is "com.lawcrossing.apps".

Also when i went into my pods/Fabric/ and click on "run" CLI. It clearly says

> Firebase mode detected. warning: unable to find
>   GoogleService-Info.plist in app bundle, dSYMs will not be uploaded

BUT actually plist is present. I had tried it deleting it and re-added the plist file. I also tried with the Firebase.configure (withoptions) by explicit defining the path and filename of plist.

Comment: Do not test on simulator, You need to test on real device. I had same issue but working fine on real device

Comment: Thanks? Do you have a Fabric entry in your info.plist? It seems like this is reporting to an old dashboard. - Todd from Fabric

Comment: @ToddBurner I am using GoogleService-Info.plist file from the Firebase console using Crashlytics. There will be no such entry of Fabric.

Comment: hey how did you end up solving this issue i am getting the same. Unable to find the dsym in dashboard.

Comment: how did you solved this issue?. I tried all the above scenarios but no luck. Issue keep on reproducing. @Dell

Answer (score 0):

Make sure GoogleService-Info.plist file's Target Membersip of your main target is checked

[image]

(Select the GoogleService-Info.plist file in the project navigator, Target Membership options will be on the far right)

To address the comments: you can test on the simulator, testing on the real device is not required for this to work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the GoogleService-Info.plist to the *Input Files* section in the Run Script phase for Fabric:

[image: Xcode Run Script Phase for Crashlytics / Fabric]

Comment: @ Aodh You put me in the right direction, I had a script `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
´  that made me cash the Arciving with the error ` `Not able to read GoogleService-Info.plist at path...`I just deleted that second script and it now archives perfectly.
Dough in the ru script I don have to add the path to the `GoogleService-Info.plist`..